# Give another action for JPA EntityManager persist() method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, procedure

I want to, when persist (maybe merge too) method is executed, he calls a procedure in DB instead of make an instance managed and persistent (original action).

It's possible?

Comment: Do you want to call stored procedure when something is saved/persisted/merged?

Comment: Yes, when I have something to save/persist/merge. Using the persist and merge methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Hibernate [Interceptors or Events](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/events.html) for that case.

If you would like to only call this only on a few occasions, `annotate` the Entity with custom annotations. And within the newly created Interceptor use refactoring and find if the saved entity has the annotation. If annotation is present then call the desired stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to make the INSERT or UPDATE of the entity using a stored procedure when the persist method is executed,  not save the entity and call the stored procedure later

Comment: @Márcio Yes, using Interceptors you can actually skip the save into DB and call the storedprocedure. You can give it a try